# iOS storyboard layout

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard

I am working on an app and have come into some graphical problems when designing my app.

First off, my app is only support by iPhone. My current storyboard is using the iPhone 5 as the screen size, so everything screws up when I try to run in iPhone 4 and 4S. Is there a way to make multiple storyboards for each different screen size? Or do you all have another solution?

Thanks!
- Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small button in the lower right hand corner that lets you toggle between 3.5" and 4" screen sizes so you can see how it will look on different devices. By using Auto Layout introduced in iOS 6 you can make sure to set up your constraints so that your UI looks good on both older and newer iPhones.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the Auto Layout feature?

Comment: There is a checkbox that says "Use Autolayout" in the file inspector in your storyboard. You can add constraints by dragging them in from the object library.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to make different storyboards for separate screen sizes, but another way to do it is like this:

Whenever you add objects to your views, be sure to have them aligned to something (using constraints). If all items are relative to other items, then most likely the layout will be fine on all devices. Also, if you find that your controls start overlapping, then perhaps you ran out of room. In that case simply add a scroll view to your layout, and then put the controls on top of it. Then, it won't scroll on the larger screens because all controls are shown, but on smaller devices it will allow you to scroll down to see the rest of the objects.

Good luck.